# Difficulty passing complex JSON objects to RESTful service from android app

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services, wcf

I have a question on the implementation of android -> JSON -> RESTful WCF webserive architecture. I'm primarily coming from a C# pattern based background so finding the android architecture hard to get my head around. The way I have designed my C# webservice is to have a whole "model" namespace that defines all my business objects such as User, UserProfile, UserSearchCriteria, UserPhoto etc as CLR objects.

I have exposed my webservice interface through WCF using the RESTful model, combined with request/response pattern which I am used to. One example of a REST web method is as follows.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/GetSeeds"
            )]
        GetSeedsResponse GetSeeds(GetSeedsRequest request);
```

Response object

```
[DataContract]
    public class GetSeedsResponse
    {
        public GetSeedsResponse(List<Seed> seeds)
        {
            Seeds = seeds;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Seed> Seeds { get; set; }
    }
```

Request object

```
[DataContract]
    public class GetSeedsRequest : BaseRequest
    {
        public GetSeedsRequest(int userId, int numberToTake, int startPosition)
        {
            NumberToTake = numberToTake;
            StartPosition = startPosition;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int NumberToTake { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int StartPosition { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Note: all my request objects inherit from my own custom base request object which merely provides them all a common header for authentication, as follows (I am not sure if this is the best way to handle authentication but it is what I am familiar with so have done it this way for now)

```
[DataContract]
    public abstract class BaseRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
    }

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.2022")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:MyStory:Web:Services:ServiceModel:Headers")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="urn:MyStory:Web:Services:ServiceModel:Headers", IsNullable=true)]
    public class Header
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string SessionToken { get; set; }
    }
```

So far I have managed to successfully call the RESTful webmethod from android with the following code in an AsyncTask background worker.

```
protected ArrayList<Seed> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI);

            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("UserId", 1);
            data.put("NumberToTake", 10);
            data.put("StartPosition", 0);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString());
            post.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
           }
...
}
```

I would then seek to extract the response and manually construct a "Seed" object based on an android class I would define, matching the properties of the CLR version, and manually extracting from the JSON response the indexed fields for which I would know which one corresponded to which property.

My question is in two parts

1) I cannot figure out how to pass the header object. I have tried the following

```
JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
            header.put("UserId", 1);
            header.put("SessionToken", "");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("UserId", 1);
            data.put("NumberToTake", 10);
            data.put("StartPosition", 0);
data.put("Header", header);
```

But this fails to work with a generic "Bad request error" exception and the webservice doesn't even enter the webmethod (I have set a break point on line 1 which gets hit without the header, but doesn't get hit when I include the header), so I assume I am not understanding JSON properly or the way to pass an embedded object in the Request object

2) Am I doing the whole architectural approach correct? It seems quite laborious and prone to error to be manually constructing array indexed requests and responses for every web service call. How should I be structuring my project, creating matching android objects for all CLR objects my webservice wants to accept as parameters or return as response objects? Is there a lot more power to JSON that I am not aware of that I should be using? With the requests, do I need to create bespoke individual AsyncTask objects for every single web service call I might make? There are about 40 different web methods my app will call, does this mean 40 AsyncTask objects kept in a package somewhere in my codebase? I'm struggling to figure out the "best practices" for designing a decent sized app with decent amounts of web service interaction, if anyone has any books they could reccomend or tutorials that touch on best practices for android project design, architecture for my scenario then I would be very grateful.

Apologies for the length of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decouple the Android side from the Windows server side.  The reason we use JSON and REST is that they are system agnostic.  Don't worry about the structure on the Windows side. Instead focus on what JSON request will work for the server, and focus on creating that JSON on Android.

First, get a REST client like [POSTMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and figure out what the REST call looks like, and what the JSON body looks like.

Then, figure out how to make Android send that body.

Finally, figure out how to make Android generate the JSON body programatically.  For this last one, I strongly recommend [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  It will let you work with higher level objects instead of constructing your JSON manually.  If you update your request with the JSON body I'll update this response with how it could be generated in Gson.

As a side note, I recommend you look at [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) instead of the Apache HTTP client.  It's much more full featured and robust.  This isn't necessary at all, but it will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very helpful. Just for the very first step about deciding what JSON request will work for the server, how should it be looking on my WCF service method - should I be deserializing the JSON request passed through? In that case what should be the signature of the method, a string request parameter? In one of my Request classes for example, I have three int fields and a nested complex CLR object which itself has four int fields and a string field. Would I be wanting to pass a serialized JSON representation of this entire Request CLR object as the request parameter?

Comment: Since you are doing HTTP POST, you would send the JSON in the POST body.  I am not particularly familiar with .NET server code so I can't help much on what the server is expecting, but you essentially create it by the nature of your GetSeedsRequest object.  My guess is something like:{'NumberToTake': 1,
            'StartPosition' : 2, 'UserId' = 'jdoe'}